# Creating a DE record when uploading content in Exact Target

Tags: marketing-cloud, content, dataextensions

Is it possible to create a DE record when you upload an image to the library in Exact Target with the URL of the image that I can call in a lookup?

Comment: No its not. Could you expand your use case a bit more so we know exactly what problem you are trying to solve. There may be alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Is the image being added via an API call?  If so, then you could add some additional API requests to the process to take care of this. After using the Create method with the Portfolio object to add the image to the library then do a follow-up Retrieve request on the Portfolio object to get the FileURL property for it. Make one last request to add that record to a data extension.